# WPF ComboBox change size on dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I was wondering, if there is a way to change the size of a combobox while the dropdown is opened.

I've got a StackPanel with Label's and ComboBoxes, wrapped in a Grid.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="A:"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbA"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="B:"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbB"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>

Looks like:
Label ComboBox
Label ComboBox
```

If i open a ComboBox, it should NOT overlap and look like:

```
Label ComboBox
      DropDown
      DropDown
      DropDown
Label ComboBox
```

I hope you understand me :)

Comment: IMO that's not going to be visually comfortable, from a UX perspective, because all the visual elements below the combobox will be moved down whenever the user clicks on the combobox to open it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a spacer Grid or other element between the two Comboboxes? You'll need to set the `MaxDropDownHeight` on `cbA`. If there are fewer elements than the default height allows for, the space will be too big.

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="A:"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cbA" MaxDropDownHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboTest}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Spacer" Height="{Binding ElementName=cbA, Path=MaxDropDownHeight}" 
                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cbA, Path=IsDropDownOpen, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="B:"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cbB"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: @RameshMuthiah - you should probably upvote Jelly's answer, then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want like this
[image]

This is ListPicker control. Combobox don't work like this.